# How to find out if a method is supported in Firefox addons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm converting a Chrome extension to Firefox, and here's one method:

webRequest.onAuthRequired(...)

> browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired()
>
> TypeError: browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired is not a function [Learn More]

Nevertheless, webRequest/onAuthRequired is [described in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onAuthRequired).

I installed **Firefox 50**, but still it's absent. Is it present in some development builds, and how to find this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> webRequest/onAuthRequired is described in the docs.

Yes, with an explicit support table that outright says **No** for Firefox.

MDN extension documentation mirrors Chrome docs even for bits not supported in FF, as they see themselves as a central documentation for all browsers.

If you want to check actual support, see one of these resources:

- [Are we WebExtensions yet?](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/) (best place to find bugs that track implementation)
- [Browser support for JavaScript APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs) (good place to find minimum supported version)
- [Chrome incompatibilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities)

Then, if there is an API that's not yet supported, you should check that it exists in the namespace before using it:

```
if (browser && browser.webRequest && browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired) {
  // browser.webRequest.onAuthRequired is not yet supported,
  //   see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190689
} else {
  // Can use it
}
```

There's no better (runtime) way to check support. It gets even more complicated when an API is partially supported, e.g. `notifications` features - there's no general way.

---

P.S. Note that `browser` is a Firefox-only (for now, at least) variation of extension API - the only difference being that it returns Promises from async functions if no callback is specified. If you don't use that, stick to the `chrome` namespace for maximum portability.

Comment: Somehow I missed that table. Thanks!